# How can I implement a separate Actionbar for a fragment other than its parent activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an Activity A which consist of two fragments!!
when I opened the activity one fragment of list fragment type has been shown on clicking the list item a new fragment containing the detail of list is opened by replacing the current list fragment!
Now I want to implement a separate action bar for detail fragment, Can anybody suggest a good link or some hint for that!!

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for this element on Android: [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Is new in Android 5 (API 21) but you can use support library v7 for older versions.